# C - почему происходит переорпеделение если тип не указан?

Tags: c

Почему выполняется данный пример и значение переменной "A" выводится как символьный тип? Т.е почему он из int делает ее char при том, что мы не инициализировали снова переменную с новым типом. Если будем пытаться инициализировать ее с указанием типа char - то тогда будет ошибка. Что происходит в памяти не совсем понимаю. Мы зарезервировали место под int сначала, как потом у нас это место меняется на char? Они же разного размера. Или это потому-что в памяти они хранятся (char) как число?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int A = 66;
      A = 'd';
  
printf("%c\n", A);    
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? `'d'` — просто целое число. `%c` — всего лишь пояснение, что вместо числа надо вывести соответствующий ему символ...

Comment: 1) `Мы зарезервировали место под int сначала, как потом у нас это место меняется на char? Они же разного размера`. Объём памяти занимаемой переменной `A` и тип не меняются. Вы можете написать `unsigned long long A = (short)-1;`. Тип переменной `A` не изменится, просто произойдёт _неявное приведение типа_. Значение типа `short` будет преобразовано к значению типа `unsigned long long`.

Comment: 2) Здесь: `int A = 'd';` вообще не нужно никакое приведение, т.к. в C символьные константы имеют тип `int` и значение определяемое используемой [кодировкой](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0). 3) Функция `printf` определяет тип аргумента и способ вывода с помощью _спецификатора преобразования_. Спецификатор `%c` говорит функции `printf`, что переданный аргумент имеет тип `int`, и хранимое в нём значение нужно интерпретировать как символ.